# Android SQLite deleting a specific row from database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am trying to do a simple login page where I am able to delete a specific contact with its details just by entering the username.

In other words, I would like to delete a specific row in my database.

```
    public int deleteUsername(String content){

    String whereClause = KEY_CONTENT1 + "= '" + content + "'";

    return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, whereClause, null);
}

public int deletePassword(String content){

    String whereClause = KEY_CONTENT2 + "= '" + content + "'";

    return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, whereClause, null);
}
```

```
  public void onClick(View v) {

    String username = null;
    String password = null;

    username = this.txtnewuserinputedituser.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
    password = this.txtnewpasswordinputedituser.getText().toString().toUpperCase();


    switch (v.getId())
    {

    case R.id.btndeleteuser :
    {   


        mySQL.openToWrite();
        mySQL.deleteUsername(username);
        mySQL.deletePassword(password);;
        mySQL.close();

        String toastText = "User Deleted";
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        break;
    }
    }
    }
```

Meaning that I would have to enter the username and password in the editview in order to delete that specific user.
I found a few sources telling me to use something like this
but I tried and it doesn't work. Is there any error?

```
public int deleteRow(String showId) {
    String table_name = "MYDATABASE_TABLE";
    String where = "showId='"+showId+"'";
    return sqLiteDatabase.delete(table_name, where, null);
}
```

I would like to delete a specific row in my database just by taking the username. I input as the id for the row to be deleted. How to do so, or is there any alternatives that I can use?

Answer (score 15):

You don't need to delete every entry in the row separately. The following method should delete the row where the `username` field equals the passed `userName`. The `password` field and any other field in the row will be removed also.

```
public void deleteUser(String userName)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    try
    {
        db.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, "username = ?", new String[] { userName });
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        db.close();
    }
}
```

EDIT: if you just copy the method, you won't have to open and close the DB manually any more, so your lines

```
mySQL.openToWrite();
mySQL.deleteUsername(username);
mySQL.deletePassword(password);;
mySQL.close();
```

would become just

```
mySQL.deleteUser(username);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use simple SQL query to delete specific row 
Acc to sql

`DELETE FROM table_name WHERE some_column=some_value;`
so use

`db.execSQL("delete from  " + Message.TABLENAME +" where specific_row_to_delete=\'" + user_name );`

and if you have more then one `where` condition then you can use `AND` like

```
db.execSQL("delete from  " + TABLENAME +
            " where specific_row_to_delete=\'" + user_name +
            "\' and condition_to_delete  >= " + condtion_argument );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in case your where clause contains different type of values.

```
public void delete(int Cid,String username,String password)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        database.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_CID + "=" + Cid + " and " + KEY_UserName + "=" + username + " and " + KEY_Password + "=" + password, null);
        database.close();
    }
```

***OR***

```
 public void delete(int Cid,String username,String password)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

        database.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE " +KEY_CID+ "= '"+Cid+"'AND "+KEY_Password+"='"+password+"'" +
                "AND "+KEY_UserName+"='"+username+"'");
        database.close();

    }
```

pass parameters in `delete()` method from where you call this method.

**Example**

```
favourite.delete(Courseid,Username,Password);
```

Here `favourite` is database object that we created in our `activity()` from which we are calling `delete()` function